# UIWebview crashes on loading certain pdf document on ios7 only

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, ios7

I have **iPhone application** which uses `UIWebview` to show documents.
When I try to open certain pdf file, the app crashes with this exception:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x036925e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180,
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c2d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44,
2   CoreFoundation                      0x036923bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139,
3   QuartzCore                          0x0126bcaa     _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 190,
4   QuartzCore                          0x0126be69 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 68,
5   QuartzCore                          0x0126c56f -[CALayer setFrame:] + 799,
6   UIKit                               0x017e572c -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 302,
7   UIKit                               0x01d14bcb -[UIWebPDFViewHandler didDetermineDocumentBounds:] + 161,
8   UIKit                               0x01d0f2b4 -[UIWebPDFView didCompleteLayout] + 628,
9   WebKit                              0x069cbac1 -[WebPDFViewPlaceholder _notifyDidCompleteLayout] + 161,
10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c3f81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70,
11  Foundation                          0x026759d8 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 285,
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0361b83f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15,
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0361b295 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 437,
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0363829e __CFRunLoopRun + 910,
15  CoreFoundation                      0x03637ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467,
16  CoreFoundation                      0x036378db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123,
17  GraphicsServices                    0x035bd9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192,
18  GraphicsServices                    0x035bd809 GSEventRun + 104,
19  UIKit                               0x0178ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225,
20  Navigator                           0x0000317d main + 141,
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x041a570d start + 1
```

Obviously this specific pdf document is corrupted, but the `UIWebview` crashes only on **iOS7**. on **iOS6** devices and simulator the file is not shown but the application survives.

I would love if anyone could explain the source for this difference, and more important - how to avoid such situations from crashing my app.

Edit: you can try and play with a sample project i have created to show the problem.
The project is here: https://github.com/eliktz/testWebViewProject
You can see how the application crashes on the corrupted file when running on **ios7 simulator**, and survives on **ios6 simulator**

Answer (score 0):

Add this delegate method to avoid crashing when there is a load error.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error description]);
}
```

Now to why UIWebView changed behavior between two iOS releases there is no specific answer. Lots of APIs change during major updates.

In your case make the property strong in your .h file (now it is weak) and conform to the UIWebView protocol:

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * fileName;
    - (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
```

and in your viewWillAppear method set:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.fileName==nil) {
        self.fileName=@"samplePDF";
    }
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
     [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nikos, but the app crashes before this method is being called

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524599/uiwebview-crashing-on-second-pdf-load-request

Comment: Thanks again, but i saw this thread earlier and the problem there is not my problem

Comment: Edited my answer. Tried it and it works, it logs the error: testWebViewProject[10572] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.

Comment: Notice that now the UIWebview just doesn't load right, and probably fails before it handles the document. i see that the good document is failing here too.